# PFQuery findObjectsInBackground return nil.Why?

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform, pfquery

If I use `[query includeKey@"someKey"]` method 
`[query findObjectsInBackground]` return `nil`, when I dont use includeKey , findObjectsInBackground return objects with array by key @"someKey" but this array with empty objects.

**Sample of code**

```
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"PrimaryCategory"];
    //[query includeKey:@"primaryIncomesCategories"];
    [query fromLocalDatastore];

    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *PF_NULLABLE_S objects, NSError *PF_NULLABLE_S error)
     {
         if (!error && objects.count)
         {
             self.primaryIncomesCategories = [self convertPFObjectToFBAPFCategory:objects.firstObject[@"primaryIncomesCategories"]];
         }

         if(completion)
             completion();
     }];
}
```

**In log**

```
   primaryIncomesCategories =     (
    "<p><Category: 0x796f8dd0, objectId: eLiQQ0OCxV, localId: (null)> {\n}",
etc
```

If uncomment "query includeKey"  than in log:

```
(lldb) po objects
nill
```

I am saving by this way

```
    [primaryCategory setObject:incomeCategoryArray forKey:@"primaryIncomesCategories"];
    [primaryCategory pinInBackground];
```

`incomeCategory array` is it `not nill` end objets in this array `not empty.`